Как реализовать поиск по всей Википедии независимо от языка через API?
Я использую API Википедии для получения информации о слове. На данный момент я использую следующий запрос:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/{query}

Однако некоторые слова находятся в Википедии на других языках, например, на en.wikipedia.org, uk.wikipedia.org и т.д. Мне нужно реализовать универсальный поиск, чтобы введённое слово искалось по всей Википедии независимо от языка и возвращался результат.
Есть ли у Википедии API, которое поддерживает такой поиск? Если нет, как можно реализовать такой функционал?
Буду рад примерам, советам или любым альтернативным решениям. Спасибо!
Я отыскал такой endpoint по поиску но кажется это не совсем то что мне нужно и я так и не смог вытащить оттуда информацию.
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Ракета&prop=extracts&explaintext=1&format=json

